# Add a flag link on the user's profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, users, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

I've noticed a lot of users get confused on the proper procedure to report a problematic users (sock-puppeteering, cheating, etc.). [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39327/what-do-i-do-if-i-suspect-someone-of-rep-mongering)

Unfortunately, the site's procedure right now is to flag's a user's answer/question:

[image: Current Procedure]

Sometimes, nothing is wrong with a particular post, but there's a problem with the particular account itself therefore it seems unnatural to flag an answer/question.

The solution is therefore simple. Allow the user to flag an account for moderator review the same way you can flag a post. Add a simple **flag** button on the user's page. This would solve most confusion right now on how to report a problematic user.

Comment: @Andrew: There are no problem users, only problem behaviours.

Comment: @martin: < tongue-in-cheek >so people don't kill people, it's the behavior< /tongue-in-cheek >

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't know of problem-accounts had it not been for problem-posts. Certainly we couldn't call an account flag-worthy if it yielding *absolutely no problem posts*, could we? :) I would suggest hunting down some offending posts, and flagging them.

Don't forget that you can also email the team following the "contact us" link in the footer of every page.

Comment: I understand that procedure but it seems from the recent inflow of related questions on meta that it creates somewhat of a confusion.

Comment: @Jonathan: I certainly understand the procedure now. As a member of only 3 months I am still learning. Sometimes I wish there were more teaching from elder members than flagrant sarcasm at a newb's misunderstandings.

Comment: @dboarman: You've got my email address. Feel free to write anytime if you need some input regarding any SO-related issues.